# What the terms "exception strong" and "exception neutral" mean?

Tags: c++, exception

I think `exception strong` means that the program either ends successfully or if it doesn't ends successfully it leaves the data unchanged, but I am not sure what `exception neutral` means. Can someone define these two terms?

Comment: are you taking about exception safety?[L1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_safety)

Comment: It may be useful to describe the context in which you encountered these terms.

Comment: Quick search: "[what is differece between exception safe and exception neutral?](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/comp.lang.c++/L0H-3kQrcMA)" -> quoting [Balog Pal](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.lang.c++/L0H-3kQrcMA/BEt8reeVV5UJ): "_Neutral (I normally use the term "transparent" instead) means it does not 
mess with exceptions: it is safe, plus in its body will not throw a specific 
exception, neither catch one without throw it forward._"

Comment: I saw the terms in a C++ book, in the chapter about exception handling but without explanation. Maybe are similar @MarkGarcia

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From ["Exception-Safety in Generic Components"](http://www.boost.org/community/exception_safety.html):

> The strong guarantee: that the operation has either completed successfully or thrown an exception, leaving the program state exactly as it was before the operation started.

and

> In a generic component, we usually have an additional expectation of exception-neutrality, which means that exceptions thrown by a component's type parameters should be propagated, unchanged, to the component's caller.

Answer (score 4):

"Exception neutral" means that you don't catch all exceptions, but you catch only specific exceptions, leaving the other exceptions to propagate (to the higher levels of the application).

See http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_exceptions.html for more information.

You may also want to have a look at Abrahams' exceptions safety levels: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_guarantees