# Is std::vector exception neutral?

Tags: c++, c++11, exception, vector

Exception for the member function `at()`, I cannot think of exceptions being thrown by `std::vector` functions but by its allocator or by its elements constructors and assignment operators. Therefore, exception neutrality can be a very desirable guarantee when implementing your own allocators. For example, you might allocate all required memory up-front and then rely on the noexcept guarantee of an allocator to propagate to its container.

Does the C++ standard provide exception neutrality of `std::vector<T,Alloc>`?

Comment: "you might allocate all required memory" what if you cannot do that ?

Comment: define exactly what does it mean for you the term "exception neutrality"

Comment: @Arunmu If you cannot do that, then you throw early.

Comment: @DavidHaim See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16770012/what-the-terms-exception-strong-and-exception-neutral-mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides memory allocations, there is one situation where `vector` itself will also throw exceptions: the `at()` member function.

So, after `reserve()`ing sufficient memory, you are guaranteed that no exceptions will be thrown, provided that the vector's class's constructors and assignment operators (which will be called as part of modifying the vector) do not throw any exceptions either, and there are no out of range calls to `at()`.

Comment: There are no quirks involving `operator=`?

Comment: `operator=` on the vector itself would fall under the "memory allocations" category.